# Is there a way to use one class in multiple views? - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am wondering if there is a way to to use one class to perform all my calculations and be able to use this class within multiple views without having to initialise it when changing views.

What I have so far is:
Class:

```
class Calculations: ObservableObject {

     var item: Model // view1 initialises this class telling it what item is - this part I can do.

     // the rest is calculations
}
```

View 1:

```
struct view1: View {
    var item: Model
    
    @ObservedObject var performance: Calculations

    init(item: Model) {
        self.item = item
        self.performance = Calculations(item: item)
    }
    var body: some View {
        // inputs for the calculations in Calculations()
        NavigationLink(destination: view2()) { // Here I want to open another view where I then want to use what I have inputted in view1 plus what I will input in view2 to do some more maths in Calculations()
            Text("Performance")
        }
    }
}
```

View 2:

```
struct view2: View {
    // What do I need here to use Calculations()
    var body: some View {
        // Yet more inputs to use for more calculations in Calculations()
    }
}
```

What I want to know is what should I put in view2 to allow it to use Calculations() and not 'reset' the class and not clear all the data inputted from view1.

Comment: This [video](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sharing-an-observed-object-with-a-new-view) may help!

Comment: You genius. I have no idea why I couldn't find that video before. Thank you so much!